# How can I access individual layer in Geoserver similar to the arcgis rest-end urls?

Tags: geoserver

I have got Geoserver installed with map data in postgis.

When I use arcgis server to publish mapService and featureService, I can get a list of layers published under the url like following.

https://"ARCGIS-SERVER".com/arcgis/rest/services/"servcie folder"/"servcie folder"_gis_fs/FeatureServer

Further, I can access individual layers within the service and can see the list of attribute fields and data type information within the data.

Is it possible to get a similar information from geoserver? if yes, How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

obviously

http://**geoserver.com**/geoserver/**NameSpace**/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=**NameSpace:LayerName**&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json

you get a geojson quite similar to arcgis rest services through the wfs service

here is a live example http://144.76.39.165:8082/geoserver/ELPHO/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ELPHO:PARCELS_INIT&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json

Comment: Does it give field data type? (integer/string/etc.)

Comment: that's a different request called DescribeFeatureType check again a live example from the same data   http://144.76.39.165:8082/geoserver/ELPHO/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=ELPHO:PARCELS_INIT&outputFormat=application/json

Comment: also you might be interested in the GetCapabilities Service that lists all available layers.

check this geoserver link http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html

Comment: do mind though that if your app and geoserver reside in a different application server you might need either to use jsonp services or create a proxy